# Why "les" instead of "leur" or "des"?

Tags: grammaire, déterminants, possessif

> [De même, dans un pamphlet célèbre, Swift propose-t-il de résoudre les
>   problèmes économiques de l’Irlande en suggérant aux familles trop
>   nombreuses de manger **les** jeunes enfants.](http://bibliobs.nouvelobs.com/la-bibliotheque-de-l-ete/20130724.OBS0850/la-bibliotheque-de-l-ete-gulliver-c-est-pour-les-grandes-personnes.html)

Why is not **leur** or even **des** used in this sentence instead of *les*?

Aren't **leur** or **des** more appropriate for this sentence?

> ... manger **leur** jeunes enfants = to eat **their** infants

or

> ... manger **des** jeunes enfants = to eat **infants**

(generally speaking)

So why has the author of this article chosen **les** instead?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that there is not much of a difference between **leurs** (not *leur* because of the plural) and **les**. In this context where he talks to the big families of Ireland, both of them indicate that the children that would be eaten are their own children.

If you used **des**, we would lose the meaning of the sentence and it would not necessarily imply the children of those families.

If it hadn't been mentioned that he talked to the big families, **leurs** would have been more correct than **les** or **des**.